# Intersperse items in Makefile variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm generating a C header using a Makefile and want to do something like this:

```
printf '{%s, %s}\n' $(ARRAY1) $(ARRAY2)
```

except with the values in `ARRAY1` and `ARRAY2` interspersed.

Here's an example:

```
ARRAY1 := a b c d
ARRAY2 := e f g h
```

Desired output:

```
{a, e}
{b, f}
{c, g}
{d, h}
```

GNU-only solutions are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a combination of `join` and substitution references (though `patsubst` could have been used instead):

```
printf '{%s}\n' $(join $(ARRAY1),$(ARRAY2:%=,%))
```

It produces close enough to what I want, only missing the space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gmtt - The GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt).
It has a ["join tables"](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/master/README.md#call-join-tbltable1table2nil-value) function which does what you want, assuming that you use gmtt tables (nothing else but a list with the number of columns as leading element).

Comment: Nice, but I'd rather do this without requiring external libraries. I'll remember gmtt for the future though

Comment: @Samadi Considering that the effort to integrate an external lib in make is minimal (just straight source inclusion) I would at least compare both solutions on how much effort it takes to rethink them a few days after you have written them - trying to figure out your own make-code when you have forgotten most of its creation process is rather difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll accept my answer for now since it's not particularly complex, but I'll compare the two solutions.